# MVC Razor into javascript issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I tried to insert the value of a property of my model into a javascript variable, but it didn't work.

I tried the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var sample = "@(Model.MyProperty)";
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var sample = "@Model.MyProperty";
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var sample = @Model.MyProperty;
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 @{
    var sample = Model.MyProperty;
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: are you sure that this markup isn't valid or other contruction don't intefere? Seems just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sample = "@Model.MyProperty";
</script>
```

What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks, was a viewmodel issue (30 minutes looking at the wrong place) :-)